# Removing duplicate entries in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm very new to computing, and we've been asked to make an index which reads through lines of text one at a time, writes down particular words, and which lines they appear on. I have managed to do this, however, if a word appears on the same line more than once, it prints the line it's on twice, and this is not allowed for my test.

```
line = 1 
x = raw_input ( "Type in line 1 of the paragraph: " ).lower()
text = []
d = {}

while x != ".":
    x = convert_sentence(x)
    text = [x]
    text = string.join(text)
    text = string.split(text)
    for word in text:
        if word in d:
            d[ word ] += [line]
        else:
            d[ word ] = [line]
    x = raw_input ( "Enter a full stop to stop: " ).lower()
    line += 1
print "the index is"
for index in d:
    print index, ":", d[ index ]
```

This is the output produced when I run it:

```
the index is:
blow : [1, 1]
north : [2, 2]
brisk : [1]
youth : [2]
yesteryear : [4]
wind : [1, 3, 4]
```

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add continue after d[word]+=line

Comment: Just check `if not line in d[word]`, and if so add it. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the line you found isn't already been added to the entry. To do so you need to check `if not line in d[word]`. Also, to add an element to a `list`, you can use the `.append()` method, which is more comprehensible than the `+` operator.

Here's the correct code:

```
line = 1
x = raw_input ("Type in line 1 of the paragraph: ").lower()
text = []
d = {}

while x != ".":
    x = convert_sentence(x)
    text = [x]
    text = string.join(text)
    text = string.split(text)
    for word in text:
        if word in d:
            if not line in d[word]:
                d[word].append(line)
        else:
            d[word] = [line]
    x = raw_input ("Enter a full stop to stop: ").lower()
    line += 1
print "the index is"
for index in d:
    print index, ":", d[index]
```

Comment: @AlexHarrisonTas you're welcome! If my answer solved your question please mark it as correct so that your question will be solved and future users will benefit from it.